# Android - ListView not refreshing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-dialogfragment

I have a fragment class containg a button and Listview, when the button is clicked a DialogFragment will appear ontop of the fragment class. It will take the users input and add it into a database, everything works however the listview does not update, I know I need to call adapter.notifyDataChange() I will write the psudeo code.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //New DialogFragment show.dialog

        }
    });

    filllist(view);

    return view;
}
```

Another class, the creation of my DialogFragment

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){


    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    build.setView(view);

    build.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final String text = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.randomtext)).getText().toString();


                //Call insert method of database helper. pass user input
                //dismiss 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });

    build.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog.create();

}
```

When the user finishes filling in editText fields and presses add inserts data in database and dismisses dialogFragment but it does not update/refresh the listview, where can I call notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually change backing data of your listview before you call `notifyDataSetChanged`. For example, if you created your adapter as following:

```
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, R.layout.item_listview_layout, mData);
```

then you need to update your `mData` field and only then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Okay so do I need to create a new method calling  mAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, R.layout.item_listview_layout, mData); then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. As a fragment do I call this method in onActivityCreated?

Comment: Before I can answer this question, could you post how your `adapter` variable in DialogFragment is initialized?

Comment: adapter is just my custom layout for one listview and mapping out the data obtained in a TextView but I initialized it by CustomAdapter adapter; making an instance of CustomAdapter. I will most likely need to call notifydatachange in my fragment class either onActivityCreated but not onCreateView

Comment: You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` right after you updated your db and updated whatever data (list, array, etc) your provided to your CustomAdapter.

Comment: Where would I need to call it? in my custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple solution. Everytime before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` you always have to update the list attached to adapter. For example if you have function naming `setListData()` which fills the data for you in adapter list, you have call it before `notifyDataSetChanged()`. (note setDataList() is just a blind example as you haven't shared this code, your code may vary)

As simple as that ! Hope it works ✌